# How to apply specific plugins to affect all sites (Multisite Network)

Tags: multisite, network-admin

Is there any way how to APPLY plugins to all sites in network? And that does not mean that plugin will be "running" on the site.

I need that the plugin is affecting all sites.

i.e. hide text in administration, remove a metabox while editing etc.

(I have a plugin that does that and it worked before I installed Network. But now if I activate it it does nothing.)

I have not find any solution yet. Also why does activated plugins in network does not have any settings available? i.e. Adminize etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a folder `/wp-content/mu-plugins/` and put the plugins there.

> Must-use plugins (a.k.a. mu-plugins) are plugins installed in a
>   special directory inside the content folder and which are
>   automatically enabled on all sites in the installation. Must-use
>   plugins do not show in the default list of plugins on the Plugins page
>   of wp-admin – although they do appear in a special Must-Use section –
>   and cannot be disabled except by removing the plugin file from the
>   must-use directory, which is found in wp-content/mu-plugins by
>   default.
>   [WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Must_Use_Plugins)